# laravel 5.2 how to make href inside Form::select

Tags: laravel-5, laravelcollective

I have:

```
{{ Form::select("toLeague",$select_leagues,null, ['class' => 'selectpicker']) }}
```

I want to do each league in $select_leagues as a link with it's id like:

```
<a href="league/albums/{league->id}">
```

How to  do this?

Comment: You can't use links inside a select! One option would be to use javascript to redirect on change of the select.

Answer (score 1):

You need use onchange javascript event and redirect

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#idSelect').change( function() {
      location.href = 'league/albums/'+$(this).val();
   });
});
```

Or using jquery:

```
$('#idSelect').bind("change keyup",function()
{

  window.location = 'league/albums/'+$(this).val();
});
```